# react-native-sound, Gaps between loops (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, playback

I'm using [react-native-sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound) to playback looped audio files (exactly mp3 format). The problem is that there is a gap between the loops.
Here is my code example:

```
    loadSound = (s) => {
  let sound = new Sound(s, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
      return;
    } else {
      sound.setNumberOfLoops(-1);
    }
  });

  return sound;
}

let sound = loadSound('campfire.mp3')
sound.play();
```

Is there any workaround how to make the loops to sound smooth?

Actually, this [issue](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/issues/323) is open on github, but there is no solution yet...

Answer (score 4):

There are gaps between loops because of the bug in Android MediaPlayer (which is used under the hood).
To fix the problem I've created the [react-native-audio-exoplayer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-audio-exoplayer) module, which has pretty same functionality as the [react-native-sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound), but it is based on the Android [ExoPlayer](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/). The API is a bit different but more robust and modern (have a look at the [docs](https://github.com/kyrylenko/react-native-audio-exoplayer#usage-playing-sounds)).
Later if I have time I'll do a pull request to introduce ExoPlayer in the react-native-sound.
But for now feel free to use [react-native-audio-exoplayer](https://github.com/kyrylenko/react-native-audio-exoplayer) as a good workaround (for now it's implemented only for Android).

Comment: Hi Pavlo, is it a big deal adding ExoPlayer in react-native-sound? We have a project that uses react-native-sound, but this gap when looping is a deal-breaker. Your library has totally different interface and doesn't support iOS, which probably a reason we didn't switch to, because maintaining two separate codebases is against the idea of cross-platform approach. Can you help on adding this functionality to react-native-sound?

Comment: @Volder Hard to estimate, but it definitely requires some efforts...
Also, I decided to stop maintaining my react-native-audio-exoplayer in favor of [Expo Audio](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/)
So if you're ok with using Expo - use Expo Audio, it works smoothly and covers both platforms.
p.s. initially, Expo Audio didn't support playing sound in background, but now it's fixed

Comment: ok, this is pity to hear you don't maintain it anymore, because we thought about splitting the code for Android and iOS. We've seen Expo Audio, but we don't use Expo (bare React Native instead). We checked plenty of sound libraries and it seems all of them have flaws, e.g. doesn't play in background, or doesn't allow to play multiple sounds at a time, or like with react-native-sound this gap between the loops.

Answer (score 0):

Using the below version of the react-native-sounds fixed the gap issue.

https://github.com/Menardi/react-native-sound-gapless.git

From the README of the git repo:

> Simply setting a track to loop on Android does not make it gapless,
> instead leaving a short silence before restarting the track. However,
> Android does actually support gapless playback between different
> tracks. So, this fork essentially loads the same track twice, and gets
> Android to handle the gapless playback for us. The downside is that
> you will use more memory than before, because the track is loaded
> twice. For most cases, this shouldn't matter, but you can profile your
> app in Android Studio if you are concerned.

Answer (score -1):

I have same issue with looping the sound. What I did to make it work is to call the same play sound function once sound play completed. I hope this will helps you.

```
function playBackground(){
  bgSound = new Sound(bgMusic, (error, sound) => {
    if (error) {
      alert('error' + error.message);
      return;
    }

    bgSound.play((success) => {
      if(success)
      {
       // console.log("Play completed");
        playBackground();
      }
      bgSound.release();
    });
  });

}
```